# extjs- checkboxgrid check boxs unselecting on clicking different column in grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs5

I am using checkboxmodel grid in extjs for display values.

after selecting multiple row checkboxs, if i click different column all selected checkbox are unselecting. how to stop this.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/18bj

Comment: Please include the code you're having trouble with in the question.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker i already added fiddle

Comment: Yep, and that's definitely helpful (thanks for including it!), but in order to help future users its best to include the code itself in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `checkOnly: true` on the selection model:

> True if rows can only be selected by clicking on the checkbox column,
>   not by clicking on the row itself. Note that this only refers to
>   selection via the UI, programmatic selection will still occur
>   regardless.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/18bo

Comment: Thx @CD..  need another help. how can i make price cell editable after clicking checkbox.